# Cluster adjacent Vornoi polygons of same category

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, delaunay, voronoi

We have a set of points, each with (x,y) coordinates and a category C. We have built the Voronoi diagram based on these points and would now like to "cluster" adjacent polygons when they are of a particular category. Is there a ready-made algorithm / R package for doing this ?

If not, our current thinking is to go back to the Delaunay triangulation and brute-force our way to the solution : consider each vertix V, find the vertix v of each edge going into V and see if they are the same category, if so aggregate the polygons. 
Is there a better way to do that ? Is there an R package that could do that ? If not, which R package implementing Delaunay would have the best result data-structure to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Note: **I wouldn't call this cluster analysis**. If you stick to this keyword, you will not find anything useful to you. What you apparently want to do is *merge adjacent Voronoi cells*,  but that's about it.

Your Voronoi cell / Delaunay triangulation algorithm *should* give you information of all the edges. What you probably want to do is **iterate over all edges**, and when both cells have the same category, merge them.

Trivial code; and heavily application dependant (what is "same category"?), so you probably won't find a "libary" for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a convex hull on the points and remove all points inside a same category. Then repeat the voronoi diagram. BTW. I know nothing about R.